# clear the screen and move the element in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-loop

I am working on a car racing game in HTML5 canvas and JS. So when a car move then I want to clear the previous screen and move the car. But it's not working as expected.

Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var y = 110;
var x = 10;
var speed = 0.5;

function movePlayer(){
  //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  var player = new Image();
  player.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/J/W/v/e/2/z/vertical-top-view-of-car-md.png";
  player.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(player, x, y, player.width*0.4, player.height*0.13);
  }

  y = y - speed;

  if (y < -15){
    y = 110;
  } 

  requestAnimationFrame(movePlayer);
}

requestAnimationFrame(movePlayer)
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/jackysatpal/6j4c5dod/1/

Comment: Well one thing you don't need to keep creating a new image and setting the source. Do that once, outside the move function.

Comment: Oh man, that was a silly mistake. Thanks, I changed the code but now element is not moving.

Comment: For me the image does not even show up on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Patrick Evans, I figured out what was the problem. 
Made a mistake by creating a new image and setting the source. Changed the code and it's working now.

Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var y = 110;
var x = 10;
var speed = 1.5;

var player = new Image();
player.src = "./images/p1.png";

function movePlayer(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(player, x, y, player.width*0.4, player.height*0.13);

  y = y - speed;

  if (y < -15){
    y = 110;
  } 

  requestAnimationFrame(movePlayer);

}

requestAnimationFrame(movePlayer)
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/jackysatpal/6j4c5dod/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your code further by starting the drawing cycle when the image is loaded:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var y = 110;
var x = 10;
var speed = 0.5;

var player = new Image();
player.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/J/W/v/e/2/z/vertical-top-view-of-car-md.png";
player.onload = function(){
  requestAnimationFrame(movePlayer)
}

function movePlayer(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();

  context.drawImage(player, x, y, player.width*0.4, player.height*0.13);

  y = y - speed;

  if (y < -15){
    y = 110;
  } 

  requestAnimationFrame(movePlayer);
}
```